# Why i don't see response when I type in browser IP and port where nodejs is listening?

Tags: html, node.js, express, server, vps

I'm trying to understand how nodejs server works and how to get NodeJs server to send an Html when I send a request to do it.

I have a nodejs with express in a VPS. In the same VPS i host a webpage through vesta. I have a code to listen in one port (4000) and I want it to send an Html. when I run the node file I have the feedback that server is listening, but when I type the IP of the webpage and the port in my browser (IP:4000) I get This site can’t be reached.

I'm not using port 8080 because that port is already in use by HTTP and I get the error listen EADDRINUSE :::8080

What am I missing?

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

const PORT = 4000;

app.get('/about', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile('./views/page.html', { root: __dirname });
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at: http://localhost:${PORT}/`);
});
```

Comment: Do you try IP:4000 or IP:4000/about?
If you simply try to res.send("testing"), it works well?
What is the exact file location in your project tree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that your VPS is listening to port 4000.

Comment: I see in the console "Server running at: http://localhost:4000", and I assumed that means that my VPS is listening to that port. Am I right in that assumption?

Comment: The console means that Node app inside the VPS machine will listen to that port, but you need to open that port in your VPS machine itself to listen for the inbound requests that's coming from the outside world.